# I have to enter a first name, last name, student id, and avg and have it displayed on a line separated by commas on a new csv file. How do I do this?

Tags: java, csv, file, new-operator, printwriter

Here is my updated code. Again, the instructions are as follows: "Enter a first name, last name, student id, and avg, then have those 4 things displayed in a new csv file, with each of the 4 inputs separated by a comma in each record." This code works well, is there anything I can do better? Also, is "in.close()" necessary in this case since I am not reading a file, but rather user input?

```
public class Homework07 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Welcome! This program will store student records that you enter.");
    System.out.println("When you are done entering student records, simply type in 'Done' .");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("students.csv");
    
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Please enter the first name: ");
        String firstName = in.nextLine();
        if (firstName.equals("Done")) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.print("Please enter the last name: ");
        String lastName = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the student ID: ");
        int studentId = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter the current average: ");
        double currentAvg = in.nextDouble();
        in.nextLine();
        String newRecord = (firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " + studentId + ", " + currentAvg);
        
        outFile.println(newRecord); 
    }
    
    in.close();
    outFile.close();
}
```

}

Comment: You need a dummy in.nextLine() after you read the int studentId and double currentAvg.

Answer (score 0):

your code capture the enter key entered by user to I added an empty `in.nextLine();` to escape it, and secondly I added `outFile.flush();` to flush the stream to the file.

```
System.out.println("Welcome! This program will store student records that you enter.");
System.out.println("When you are done entering student records, simply type in 'Done' .");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("students.csv");

while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please enter the first name: ");
    String firstName = in.nextLine();
    if (firstName.equals("Done")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.print("Please enter the last name: ");
    String lastName = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the student ID: ");
    int studentId = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter the current average: ");
    double currentAvg = in.nextDouble();
    in.nextLine();
    outFile.write(firstName + "," + lastName + "," + studentId + "," + currentAvg);
    outFile.flush();
}

in.close();
outFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to the **Scanner#nextDouble()** method does not consume the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key hit (the newline character) therefore you need to do it yourself by placing this line: `in.nextLine();` directly **under** this line:

```
double currentAvg = in.nextDouble();
```

Ironically, you need to apply a newline character when you write to your file for every record you want to save, like this:

```
String record = new StringBuilder(firstName).append(", ").append(lastName)
                    .append(", ").append(studentId).append(", ")
                    .append(currentAvg).append(System.lineSeparator())
                    .toString();
outFile.write(record);
```